# how to make a video player in javafx in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, video, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a video player using javafx in eclipse. I followed the steps shown in a youtube video (url : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4ehYIynI34 ) from time 05:00:33.

But while compiling I get an exception in the start method.

Main.java

```
package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,852,280,Color.BLACK);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("VideoGenic");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The following is the controller program.

Controller.java

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MediaView mv;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Media me;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


        String path = new File("application/src/media/vid1.mkv").getAbsolutePath();
        me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);


    }
}
```

This is the fxml file.

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <center>
      <MediaView id="mv" fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

THis is the error I got.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
error:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Maha%20Dev/eclipse-workspace/VideoGenic%20MediaPlayer/bin/application/Main.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Maha Dev\eclipse-workspace\VideoGenic MediaPlayer\application\src\media\vid1.mkv (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:407)
    at application.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:25)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Comment: The exception message is quite clear - `MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Maha Dev\eclipse-workspace\VideoGenic MediaPlayer\application\src\media\vid1.mkv` - it can't find your mkv file. Correct the path in your program.

Comment: I tried correcting it to all possible ways I know. either it shows :  Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : Unrecognized file signature!

Comment: or something like this                   Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\Maha Dev\eclipse-workspace\VideoGenic MediaPlayer\src\media\vid.mkv (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: I also tried using an .mp4 video file. Same problem